# JUnit test failing because some properties not read

Tags: selenium, junit, jenkins

I have a selenium tests written in Junit that I'm running via a Jenkins job.  The tests execute fine from Eclipse and from my local command line (Win7).  The tests only fail when I execute them via Jenkins.

When I run the tests via  a Jenkins job, a handful of the tests fail.  After some investigation I found that some properties, which are read at run time from a properties file, are being successfully read, while others aren't.  Of 30 properties read, 9 will fail, and be set to null for test execution, which causes the test to fail.

I'm only reading from one properties file.  If I change one of the failing constants to read a different property, it reads fine.  Which makes me think there's a problem with the properties file, but I've looked it over and it looks fine.

Here's a snippet of the code I using to read the properties file:

> Properties uiStrings = new Properties(); 
>   ...
>
> InputStream isStrings =
>   LandingPage.class.getResourceAsStream("/locale_" + locale);
>   uiStrings.load(isStrings); ...
>
> BROWSE_PANEL_TEXT = uiStrings.getProperty("browse_panel_text");
>   HOME_BUTTON_TITLE =
>   uiStrings.getProperty("home_button_title");

In the above, the BROWSE_PANEL_TEXT is undefined, while HOME_BUTTON_TITLE is set as expected.  The properties are defined in a separate file as follows:

> browse_panel_text=Browse
>
> home_button_title=Home

As near as I can tell the syntax for defining the property strings are identical between failing and succeeding reads.  The syntax for reading the file is identical as well.  I'm stumped.

I developed the tests on a Win7 machine, the tests are executing on the Mac.

Thanks in advance.
R

Comment: What is meaning locale_? Maybe you has different locale on both machines (en_US, en_GB) and the property file does not have requested values. Add log `System.out.println("/locale_" + locale)`